# ionic: Fixed title in ion-nav-bar

Tags: ionic-framework, navbar

I'm trying to get a fixed title in the ion-nav-bar (text or image). For a app i'm building I just need a back icon and a logo/brandname in the navbar that doesn't fade from view to view.

Can anyone help me/give me a hint to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same here...did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use this body in your index.html.
Put the content of your header bar in . Don't declare ion-nav-bar in any of your templates, so that they will inherit the header from index.html.

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
        <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon">
            <i class="ion-arrow-left-c"></i> Back
        </ion-nav-back-button>
        Your logo/name
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view>
    </ion-nav-view>
</body>
```